# Is there a way to cancel StorageFile.CopyAsync()?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

In Win8, I use somefile.CopyAsync(destFolder, newName) to copy files. But when I try to cancel it, it appears doesn't work.
These two method are how I try to cancel it:

1. just use IAsyncOperation.Cancel

   ```
   var op = somefile.CopyAsync(destFoder, newName);
   op.Cancel();
   op.Complete = (x,y) =>
   {
       switch(y) {
           case AsyncStatus.Complete:
               Debug.WriteLine("Completed" + x.GetResults().Name);
               break;
           case AsyncStatus.Cancel:
               Debug.WriteLine("Canceled")
               break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. use AsTask(CancellationToken)

   ```
   var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   var op = somefile.CopyAsync(destFolder, newName).AsTask(cts.Token);
   await op;
   ```

In first method, case AsyncStatus.Cancel doesnt be called, and in second method, nothing happens too.Is there any other way I can try? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this...

```
var task = file.CopyAsync(KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary, "test").AsTask();
task.AsAsyncAction().Cancel();
```

It worked in my simple test.

This code should work as well if you want to use cancellation tokens

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
var token = source.Token;
token.Register(() => { Debug.WriteLine("Your cancellation code here"); });
var task = file.CopyAsync(KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary, "test").AsTask(token);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but second method using cancellationtoken doesn't work, I put task.AsAsyncAction().Cancel() in token.register area, but the copy operation still completes, so weird.

Comment: the first method doesn't work either, if I add `await task` at buttom.